# Where do I find the ogr2ogr command for Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: open-source-gis, ogr

I am looking for the equivalent of FWTools for Mac OS X, Lion.  Is there anything I can easily install and get that command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find Mac GDAL downloads here: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive#gdal
OGR and the associated utilities (i.e ogr2ogr and ogrinfo) are included with GDAL.

Comment: Yup, thanks.  It gets installed to /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Programs/ogr2ogr

Comment: Or, `brew install gdal` (http://brew.sh)

Comment: @Meekohi you should add that as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: As you command.

Comment: @Meekohi I _suggested_ you add that as answer so I could vote for it. Which I have. No commands intended ;)

Comment: This version doesn't appear to include Oracle support. On windows, there is an option to include the oracle support, how would we do this here for mac?

Comment: No idea. Try homebrew and the [osgeo4mac tap](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac), it has a gdal-oracle formula

Answer (score 40):

`ogr2ogr` is part of the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL).

1. Get homebrew from http://brew.sh
2. `brew install gdal`

Answer (score 8):

Taking the information from the above, here's how you would actually get the ogr2ogr command working like it should

- add this to your `~/.bash_profile` script:

  ```
  export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.[YOURVERSIONHERE]/Programs/:$PATH
  ```

the above code also adds a bunch of other gdal libraries to your path as well

Comment: Well put @boulder_ruby - exactly what I needed!

Comment: You can also use "Current" as the [YOURVERSIONHERE]

Comment: Try restarting your computer after you add this to your path. And if that doesn't work, try adding a manual PATH variable to the QGIS settings page: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285832/gdalbuildvrt-command-not-found-in-build-virtual-raster-tool

Comment: @plnnr not necessary. To reload ~/.bash_profile just reload a new terminal or run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

`brew install gdal`

You will either have to symlink the ogr2ogr binary to your PATH our just use it directly. in my case. I found it under `/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/bin/ogr2ogr` using:

```
brew --prefix gdal
```