# "gdalbuildvrt command not found" in Build Virtual Raster tool

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdalbuildvrt

I am trying to use the "Build Virtual Raster" tool in QGIS 3 to build a mosaic. When I run the tool, I get the following message:

```
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: gdalbuildvrt: command not found
```

`gdalbuildvrt` is available in my terminal, but it appears that QGIS does not know where to find it. How do I fix this?

I am running:

- QGIS 3.0.3
- macOS 10.13.4

Comment: I have the same problem.
Tallistroan, I tried your instructions above but the problem persisted.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vf2q.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vf2q.png)
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJLsT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJLsT.png)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159415)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a know issue, however there is a workaround described in the readme file from the installer:

QGIS 3 does not find external tools needed for Processing.  Some configuration options are missing.  A workaround is to use QGIS custom variables.  Open QGIS Preferences → System.

- Under the Environment section, turn on Use Custom Variables.
- Add (+) a variable
- Select Prepend from the Apply popup
- Enter PATH for the variable
- For the Value enter:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/Programs:
- Quit QGIS 3 and start it again