# QGIS Raster Calculator missing bands

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I've created a VRT from some 6-band TIFF tiles. The VRT displays perfectly in QGIS 3.6 and I can see manipulate the band arrangement and create different composites.

However, when I open the raster calculator, it only shows one band available. If I write the calculation anyway with the band numbers ("image@2" + "image@3" ..). it does not work.

Comment: What option did you use to create a vrt. You should use the option that says Place each input file into a separate band so that you can access the individual bands in raster calculator

Comment: The source files are each multi-band tiles. They should not be combined as separate bands, because each file contains multiple bands - they are merged into one file. I suspect an issue with QGIS 3.6 and GDAL is causing an issue here because of the following issue and because the proposed solution does not fix it on my installation: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285832/gdalbuildvrt-command-not-found-in-build-virtual-raster-tool